# me muestra el codigo que contiene mi php al compilar

Tags: php, xampp

Tengo un index.php que manda a pagina.php y al momento de darle al botón de enviar el navegador me muestra el código del PHP, ¿por qué puede ser? (Estoy utilizando XAMPP y MySQL)

```
<form action="pagina.php" method="post" >
    <div class="field">
        <label for="nombre">Nombre(s)</label>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" required />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="apellido">Apellido(s)</label>
        <input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido" required />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="empresa">Nombre de la institución</label>
        <input type="text" name="empresa" id="empresa" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="personas">no. personas que asisten</label>
        <input type="text" name="personas" id="personas" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="imagen">Comprobante de pago</label>
        <input type="file" name="imagen" id="imagen" required/>
    </div>
    <ul class="actions">
         <li><input type="submit" value="Enviar" /></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

---

```
<?php
include"conexion.php";
ConectarBD();

$nombre=$_REQUEST['nombre'];
$apellido=$_REQUEST['apellido'];
$nombreins=$_REQUEST['empresa'];
$nopersonas=$_REQUEST['personas'];

$nombrearchivo=$_FILES['imagen']['name'];
$archivo=$_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];
$ruta="archivos";

$ruta=$ruta."/".$nombrearchivo;

move_uploaded_file($archivo,$ruta);

$query=mysql_query("insert into registros values('','".$nombre."','".$apellido."','".$nombreins."','".$nopersonas."','".$ruta."',)");

if($query){
    echo"Insertado correctamente";
}else{
    echo"Error al insertar";
}

?>
```

Comment: ¿El código de que fichero: index.php o pagina.php? ¿Te muestra algún error? Por favor, añade más detalles. Y lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve].

Comment: Además, el código compartido presenta graves problemas de seguridad: usa código obsoleto (y eliminado en versiones modernas) y es vulnerable a inyección sql, por lo que no debería usarse en entornos de cara al público.

Comment: gracias es que estoy comenzando a ver php y era un ejemplo de youtube pero ya se por que no me funcionaba ahora lo que me pasa es que no toma el nombre del archivo que quiero subir llega vacio en la parte de pagina.php $nombrearchivo=$_FILES['imagen']['name'];

Comment: Supongo que navegas con http://localhost o http://127.0.0.1 El problema es que el PHP no se interpreta y esto es un problema de configuración de xampp y no de programación.